# performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: not finding my segue

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a `UINavigationController` with a `UITableViewController` as `rootViewController`. I created a segue from my prototype cell of my table view and connected it with another `UIViewController`. The identifier of my segue is "Detail". In my `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of my table view delegate (which is being called), I have the following line:

```
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" sender:nil];
```

When running my application and tapping one of my cells, an exception is thrown because `'Receiver (<UINavigationController: 0x71c65b0>) has no segue with identifier 'Details''`

What can be going wrong here?

**Edit**

When I change

```
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" sender:nil];
```

into

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" sender:nil];
```

the next view is pushed, but I get these errors:

```
2012-10-19 12:32:05.128 Numbers[44850:c07] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-10-19 12:32:17.234 Numbers[44850:c07] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-10-19 12:32:17.236 Numbers[44850:c07] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <DetailViewController: 0x74a1fb0>.
```

Apparently, I shouldn't let my current view controller do the work, but my navigation view controller (that's what it's there for). Going back with the back button results in weird animations, just like the warnings warned me about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a guess, but is it possible that you wired the segue **and** trigger it by code?
If there no "special" reason, you usually do not need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`. Instead, simply wire your tableviewcells with the desired segue.

However, **if** you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`, **don't** wire it!

Comment: How would Xcode know which segue to use for a specific identifier if I didn't create it in interface builder? Should I create it programmatically? I call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` to pass an object along.

Comment: Nevermind, in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, I could access the text label of the selected `UITableView` row, which allowed me to pass the correct data to the `destinationViewController`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `Interface Builder` select the `UITableViewCell`. Connect its selection triggered `segue` to the `destinationViewController`. In your source `UIViewController` implement `prepareForSegue:` function and pass the `destinationViewController` all the pertinent info. No need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier:`

Answer (score 0):

just do this in your didselect method

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" sender:nil];

i think you are doing push in other function also thats y it is giving error for nested push or check ur push segue in storyboard that is it correctly linked to next view or not